# upload multiple images along with text fields from single form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a single form on a page. It has 6 text fields with 6 upload file fields. I need to write the text and file paths to a database. I have seen many examples online but most are to upload a single file or to upload multiple files from the same upload field.

I am new to php so any help would be very useful.

Many thanks in advance.

I have this code for uploading multiple images but can not undestand how to post the respective input fields along with these images.

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center. Please try the scripts yourself and tell us where you have problems and what you don't understand. The question needs to be more specific if you want help with the code

Comment: The question is very much about programming, it is scaling up a file upload script to a larger number of files... It can't be answered in code, but neither can many good questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to be very different for 6 fields than for one.

You need to

- add extra fields for the text and fileupload
- use PHP pick up all the submitted data
- use SQL statements to insert the data

Things to watch out for:

- every field in your form will have a name. Make the name sensible so that the work is easy to do, e.g. `name="text1"`, `name="file1"`, `name="text2"`, `name="file2"`, etc.
- Will every field be full every time? Do you need exactly 6 fields or a varying number? If you want to upload any number of files, then it's a different story. You need to use javascript, and maybe ajax, to create a 1-at-a-time upload that will be fast, informative and user-friendly.
- SQL statements, as you need to run 6 near identical statements, look at prepared statements - they are better anyway but here you have no excuse.

Update: now that your code is posted; you need to modify the code so that it will insert the file name in the database. That is not a difficult change.

To handle the text fields, there are a few ways. You could make sure that they are numbered starting with `text0`. Then, looping to go through the files, you can obtain the corresponding text field with `$_POST['text'.$i]` (`$i` being the loop counter). Alternatively, you could build up an array of text values first, then process text values and file uploads together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this?

```
<form action="">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="text" name="name1" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file1" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="text" name="name2" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file2" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="text" name="name3" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file3" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="text" name="name4" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file4" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="text" name="name5" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file5" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <strong></strong>
                <input type="file" name="file6" />
            </label>
        </li>
        <li><input type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And in the PHP, you can catch them this way:

```
<?php
    if (count($_FILES) > 0) {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clear with my question.I need to upload multiple images along with text fields.
Example:
Text 1 and Image 1
Text 2 and Image 2 and so on...

Comment: @sachinBhalerao Sorry I made a mistake in my answer! One sec.

Comment: If you have any sample code for php file that would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have anything whatever you have done?

Comment: sure..wait i am uploading my code

Comment: i have updated my question along with php code. sorry for long discussion.